# Что имеется ввиду под `Webpack 2 нативно понимает ES6`?

Tags: babel, webpack2

Я не раз слышал о том, что `Webpack 2` (в отличие от `Webpack 1.x`), нативно понимает `ES6`. Что это значит и что из этого следует?

Естественно, что после получения ответов на данный вопрос, встанет следующий вопрос о том, как же изменить настройки Babel. На данный момент я использую `webpack 2x` со следующими настройками:

**package.json**

```
  // ...  
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.22.0",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.22.0",
    // ...
    "webpack": "^2.4.1"
  }
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
// ...  
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: [
                /\.jsx?$/
            ],
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                'babel-loader'
            ]
        }            
    ]
},
// ...
```

Что из приведённых выше настроек теперь стало не нужно благодаря так называемому "нативному пониманию" ES6 инструментом Webpack?

Comment: разве там где ты _слышал_ не рассказывалось конкретнее в чем суть?

Comment: Нет. Например, процитирую слова из знаменитого [скринкаста по webpack](https://learn.javascript.ru/screencast/webpack): "Следующая версия Webpack будет понимать ES6 нативно, а текущая работает через Babel" (и дальше изложение отклоняется от следующей версии Webpack). Скринкаст замечательный, но я не понял из этой фразы, чего именно теперь стало не нужно прописывать в настройках Webpack.

Comment: [What's new in webpack 2](https://gist.github.com/sokra/27b24881210b56bbaff7)

Comment: конкретнее: [The `es2015` babel preset transforms ES6 Modules to CommonJS by default. To use webpack to process ES6 Modules you should use the `es2015-webpack` preset instead.](https://gist.github.com/sokra/27b24881210b56bbaff7#babel-and-webpack)